# How to fetch data from postgresql using NodeJs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql

Facing a problem when tried to interact with postgresql database, when entered a `root` as a `pseudo` getting error:

> column root doesn't exist:

NodeJS code:

```
app.get('/login',function(request,response){
   var username = request.query['username'];
   var password = request.query['password'];
   console.log("utilisateur "+ username +" avec "+ password +" comme mot 
 de passe");

   const pool  = new Pool(config);
   sql = 'select * from users where pseudo = "' + request.query["username"] + '";';

   pool.on('error',function(err,client){
     console.log("erreur de connexion",err);
   });

   pool.query(sql,function(err,res){
      if (err){return console.error('erreur dexécution !!',err,sql);}
      console.log('nom:', res.rows[0].nom, ' prenom:', res.rows[0].prenom,' pseudo:', res.rows[0].pseudo);

   });
});
```

users [database table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OUPHh.png)

Comment: Please share what error you are getting. Will suggest you to replace your query to this sql = `select * from users where pseudo = '${ request.query["username"] }'`; Read more about new back-tick string in javascript.

Comment: i'm getting the column "value of "request.query["username"]" doesn't exist despite it exist in my database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i just had to write my sql query like this:

```
   sql = `select * from users where pseudo = '${ username }' `;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem might be because postgresql strings require single-quotes but you are using double quotes. Try something like this:

`` sql = `select * from users where pseudo = '${username}';`; ``

But this code contains a nasty security vulnerability called [SQL injection](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp). Think about the SQL that would be sent to your database if a user entered the (fake) username `root OR 1 = 1; --`. An easy solution to this is to use [parameterized queries](https://node-postgres.com/features/queries#parameterized-query).

Comment: thanks, it solved my problem ,in spite of this it is disadvised to proceed thus

Comment: but res is undefined when i print it on the console, do you have and  sql = 'select * from users where pseudo = \'lyes \' '